# Change color of text ,ini

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Version 13

Command `bot-info` is works but I have a prob with it when I use `ini` to change the text color.

here:

````
  .addField("```ini
                'Developer'```",  'Asuka#1290')
````

The error is:

***.addField("```ini***

***SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token***

The whole Code:

````
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const os = require('os') // npm i os
const ms = require('ms') // npm i ms
const moment = require('moment') // npm i moment
const cpuStat = require('cpu-stat') // npm i cpu-stat
const db = require('quick.db') // npm i quick.db // Optional

module.exports = (client) => {
    client.on('message', message => {
        const prefix = db.fetch(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`) // Or Just Do const { prefix } = require('../../../config.json')
        if(message.content.toLowerCase() === `${prefix}bot-info` || message.content.toLowerCase() === `${prefix}bi` || message.content.toLowerCase() === `${prefix}bot`) {

            // For Status Of Bot
            const status = {
                online: ':- Online',
                idle: ':- Idle',
                dnd: ':- DND',
                offline: '⚫:- Offline'
            }
            // UpTime Of Bot
            const days = Math.floor(client.uptime / 86400000)
            const hours = Math.floor(client.uptime / 3600000) % 24 // 1 Day = 24 Hours
            const minutes = Math.floor(client.uptime / 60000) % 60 // 1 Hour = 60 Minutes
            const seconds = Math.floor(client.uptime / 1000) % 60 // 1 Minute = 60 Seconds

            // Other Stats
            cpuStat.usagePercent(function(error, percent) {
                if(error) return message.reply(error)
                const memoryusage = formatBytes(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed) // Memory Usage
                const node = process.version // NodeJS Version
                const CPU = percent.toFixed(2) // CPU Usage
                const CPUModel = os.cpus()[0].model // PC Model
                const cores = os.cpus().length // Cores
                const icon = message.guild.iconURL() // Icon Of Server

                const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(`${client.user.username}'s Statistics`, client.user.displayAvatarURL())
                .setTimestamp()
                .setThumbnail(`${icon}`)
                .setColor('#000000')
                .addField("```ini
                'Developer'```",  'Asuka#1290')
                  
                .addField('Name', `** **`+ client.user.username)
                .addField('ID', `** **`+ client.user.id, true)
                .addField('Craeted At',`** **`+ moment.utc(client.user.createdAt).format('LLLL'))
                .addField('Added To Server', `** **`+moment.utc(client.joinedAt).format('LLLL'))
                .addField('Servers',`** **`+ client.guilds.cache.size, true)
                .addField('Members In All Server', `** **`+client.users.cache.size, true)
                .addField('Channels In All Server', `** **`+client.channels.cache.size.toLocaleString())
                .addField('UpTime', `** **`+`\`${days}\` Days \`${hours}\` Hours \`${minutes}\` Minutes \`${seconds}\` Seconds`)
                .addField('Node Verison',`** **`+ node, true)
                .addField('Memery Usage',`** **`+ memoryusage, true)
                .addField('CPU USage', `** **`+`${CPU}%`, true)
                .addField('CPU Model', `** **`+CPUModel)
                .addField('Cores',`** **`+ cores, true)
                .setFooter(`${client.user.username} | This bot was created by Asuka#1290`)
                message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
            })

            // For Memory In MB, GB....
            function formatBytes(a, b) {
                let c = 1024 // 1 GB = 1024 MB
                d = b || 2
                e = ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB']
                f = Math.floor(Math.log(a) / Math.log(c))

                return parseFloat((a / Math.pow(c, f)).toFixed(d)) + '' + e[f]
            }
        }
    })
}
````

Answer (score 0):

This a pure javascript error nothing to do with your discord.js bot.

Replace your current code

````js
  .addField("```ini
                'Developer'```",  'Asuka#1290')
````

with

````js
.addField("```ini\n'Developer'```",  'Asuka#1290')
````

when using the `""` to contain a string you can't simply skip to the next line, you have to use `\n` for that.

On the other hand if you really want to skip a line you can use a backslash () before the ` to show that it's text, for example

```js
  .addField(`\`\`\`ini
                'Developer'
\`\`\``,  'Asuka#1290')
```